# android canvas custom font fill transparent areas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm using a ttf on a canvas. Since it is used by a widget I cannot use a TextView so I use drawText with a Paint object where the paint object has all the font properties set.

However the area in and around the strokes of the font is transparent, so i see only the black strokes of the font.

I know that with a textview I could use setTextColor() but is there something similar for Paint?

Comment: Do you have `paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);` ?

Comment: Yes, but it does not do the trick. I use a 3d font which has transparent areas for the character itself and it's shadow parts are what's actually drawn when using Paint.Style.FILL.  It is the default style, and the other option is Paint.Style.STROKE which just outlines the chars.

Comment: If it's just the color, you can use `paint.setColor()`...? I feel like I'm missing something, maybe you could post an image?